# Multiple GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping to be able to write a SQL query that can use multiple `COUNT`s based upon different criteria and have the values grouped together.

Let's say I have a (canned) scenario where I change the price-points of my products and want to analyze what people have paid.

```
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) as Total FROM Orders WHERE Location = 'Amazon'

SELECT Product, COUNT(*) as HighPriceCount FROM Orders 
  WHERE Location = 'Amazon' and PRICE > 10
```

From here, I'd like to be able to see results like this.

```
--------------------------------------------
| Product | Total | HighPriceCount | Avg   |
--------------------------------------------
| Game 1  | 50    | 20             | .40   |
| Prod 2  | 300   | 200            | .66   | 
--------------------------------------------
```

Where Avg. is the "price above 10" / "total sold". My initial approach is to group by `Product` but I wanted to see if an "inner-select" is the only path or whether there is a more elegant way to do this. Seems like a lot of duplication? Here's my initial version of a query.

```
-- I don't know if this works?
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) AS Total, 
(
   SELECT Product, COUNT(*) FROM Orders WHERE Location = 'Amazon' and Price > 10
   GROUP BY Product
) AS HighPriceCount,
(Total / HighPriceCount) AS Avg
From Orders
WHERE Location = 'Amazon'
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: In your outer query you have aggregate function (`COUNT`) but no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You can use `SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Amazon' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Total, SUM(CASE WHEN Location = 'Amazon' And Price > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As HighPriceCount`

Comment: Your avg is contradictory... your desired is HighPriceCount/Total, but you show the reverse in your sample code.

Comment: In the future, you should consider not using correlated subqueries. They can be performance killers and there is almost always a way to avoid them.

Comment: that's why I'm asking this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the count use a `CASE` for `HighPriceCount` as below. Aggregate functions do not count `null` except for `COUNT(*)`

[Sql-Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02957/2)

```
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) as Total, 
       COUNT(case when price > 10 then 1 end) as HighPriceCount,
       SUM(case when price > 10 then price end)/COUNT(*) as Avg
FROM Orders 
WHERE Location = 'Amazon'
GROUP BY Product
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using SUM and CASE? (can't try it right know I think it should work)

```
SELECT PRODUCT,
       SUM(CASE WHEN PRICE>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as highpricecount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN PRICE>10 THEN 1 END) as total
FROM Orders 
WHERE LOCATION='AMAZON'
GROUP BY PRODUCT;
```

Comment: The Location='Amazon' needs to apply to both Case statements and he needs the avg as well.

Comment: Since `aggregate functions are ignoring null` values, you don't need to have else part of the `case statement` in this case. Again, nothing wrong having it either.

Comment: The `COUNT(CASE WHEN PRICE>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` will simply count all the rows `WHERE LOCATION='AMAZON'` - one would need `ELSE NULL` or just exclude that part as @Kaf mentions above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine...

```
Select  Product, Total, HighPriceCount, HighPriceCount/Total As Avg
From   (Select  Product,
                Sum(Case When Location = 'Amazon' Then 1 Else 0 End) As Total,
                Sum(Case When Location = 'Amazon' And Price > 10 Then 1 Else 0 End) As HighPriceCount,
        From    Orders
        Group   By Product) o
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is mine

```
Select 
Product, Sum(Total) as Total, Sum(HighPriceCount) as HighPriceCount,Total/HighPriceCount as AVG
from 
(
select Product, 1 as Total, case WHEN PRICE>10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as HighPriceCount
from Orders where LOCATION='AMAZON'
) 
group by Product
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't work. Please try this one:

```
select A.Product, A.Total, ISNULL(B.HighPriceCount,0), B.HighPriceCount*1.0/A.Total*1.0 as [Avg]
(select Product, count(*) as Total
from Orders 
where Location='Amazon'
group by Product ) A
left join 
(SELECT Product, COUNT(*) as HighPriceCount 
from Orders 
where Location = 'Amazon' and Price > 10
group by Product) B
on A.Product = B.Product
```

I don't have your database, so maybe there is typo, I can't test this query, but with some change by you, it should work.